# Microservices broadcast messages

Tags: java, events, microservices, broadcast, mq

I'm looking for a way to broadcast messages to all clients in microservice architecture.

Right in my project I'm using RabbitMQ, and I can't achieve this without manually binding exchanges with each instance queue.

What else could I use to achieve more or less out of the box brodcasting of messages across all clients of some "channel"?

PS. Java client would be nice

Comment: What is your use case? What do you except the clients to do with the broadcasted message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fan out exchange. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html